# Array size template deduction

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, template-argument-deduction, ctad

I have a class that stores an `std::array`.

The size of the array is evaluated in compile time, this is because the application runs on an embedded device so no dynamic allocations :(.
The code looks something like this:

```
template<uint8_t size>
class A
{
    //some constructor
    A(...);
    std::array<int, size> what;
}
//Wanted use cases
A instance1({1,2,3});
//Unwanted use case
A<3> instance2({1,2,3});
```

I don't know how to construct the constructor that I want. I've tried for a week now dozens of designs and none got what I wanted.
Here are the names of thing that I have tried:

0. Template deduction guides - also templated versions, which I'm not sure if they are legal...
1. `std::initializer_list` - the size of the list cannot be put in the template argument. At least not in a non-constexpr context.
2. `std::array`
3. plain old array
4. `using` keyword - also templated.

**Tl;Dr:**

How to deduce a template parameter value signifying a size of an array type from the given array in the signature of the constructor function?

Comment: Would `A instance1 (1, 2, 3);` be acceptable syntax? Do you really need the curly braces there?

Comment: Yes that would be an acceptable syntax, this looks like using variadics, is that right?

Comment: No, that would just be a regular variadic template.

Comment: Can you elaborate or show an example?

Comment: People already wrote good answers and I'm short on time today, so I'll just leave that here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a44186c419fcde0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A small example using deduction guides:

```
template<uint8_t size>
class A
{
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    constexpr A(Args&&... args)
    : what { std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)... }
    {}
    constexpr size_t getSize() const { return what.size(); }
private:
    std::array<int, size> what;
};

//deduction guide
template <typename... Args> A(Args... args) -> A<sizeof...(args)>;

int main()
{
    //Wanted use cases
    A instance1 (1,2,3);
    static_assert (instance1.getSize() == 3);
    
    //or
    //A instance1 {1,2,3};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why `std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)` instead of `std::forward<Args>(args)`?

Comment: No reason, I guess I just typed that out cause I was using it like this recently.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <array>

template<class... U>
class A
{
    std::array<int,sizeof...(U)> what;
public:
    constexpr A(U&&... u) : what{std::forward<U>(u)...} { }
    constexpr std::size_t size() const { 
        return what.size();
    }
};

int main() {
    A a(1,2,3,4,5,6);
    static_assert(a.size() == 6);

    A b(1);
    static_assert(b.size() == 1);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is going on here?

Comment: Since  class A is based on the array (on logical level) the whole class is templated. The class has a constructor which takes any number of arguments of the same type. The constructor uses initializer list to initialize the array with perfect forwarding to avoid copying. To support different numbe of arguments we use variadic templates <class... U>. To get the number of arguments we use sizeof...(U). constexpr are used to do everything at compile time and check with static_assert.

Comment: You can skip all the constexpr and play with the code here: https://godbolt.org/z/qPKEs8